# Java - Akka project best practices

Tags: java, interface, akka

I have a java project built around the actor system. One of the actor needs to use a third party service through a java API I wrote. However I want to know if having a java interface and a utility java class that interacts with this actor is a good practice in the AKKA world?

MyActor.java

```
public class MyActor {
 @Override
 public void OnReceive(Obj o) throws Exception {
     .. do something 
     .. do something else using MyUtility.java
     .. send back the message
 }
public class MyUtility implements ItsIterface {
 ... blah
} 
interface ItsInterface {
  .. blah
}
```

Is this a good approach?

Comment: yes there's no problem with that, a fairly common approach

Comment: I think you may want to use futures here too so your calls to 'do something' are not blocking anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that as far as actor systems go, depending on a 3rd party service to seems quite natural as no-one can expect for it to work in isolation.

As far as the interface goes, I don't how it is relevant to the actor as it uses only the utility class implementation directly.
Without knowing more about `MyUtility`, if it contains state and is not used used exclusively by the actor the usual concurrency problems arise.

Though using a 3rd party service whose quality lies outside of your controls results in some potential issues and requires the design to reflect this:

- Actors blocking on a message is [discouraged](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/java/futures.html#Use_With_Actors) due to potential performance/scalability issues.
- Simply using futures from within an actor to prevent blocking transfers the bottleneck from the actor to the Future. This is especially true if you push i.e. insert messages without asking the system if it can handle the additional messages (back-pressure) .
- [Queues Don't Fix Overload](http://ferd.ca/queues-don-t-fix-overload.html) is a nice article about dealing with load in queues in general.
- It might be worth thinking about putting the 3rd party service in a separate actor and use a [circuit breaker](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/common/circuitbreaker.html) in case the service is somewhat unreliable.
- An actor seldom has the same [lifecycle](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/general/supervision.html#supervision-restart) as the service it uses, thus one needs to think about the consequences.

Hope this helps.